# Create user and block access to parent directories

Tags: permissions, directory, chown, adduser

New to terminal shenanigans here and I have set up a user using `adduser dave --no-create-home`/ Firstly, I think the user still, upon logging into the terminal, is pointed to their home directory (what was the point of `--no-create-home`).

I have also ran `chown dave:dave /var/www/sitename.com/html/ -R`.

My issue is I want to point the login straight to the `/var/www/sitename.com/html` and I don't want to allow him to `cd ../` out of it.

I'm not super new to Ubuntu but a quick google-fu hasn't netted me anything that doesn't look pretty overkill.

Thanks in advance,
Alex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you want to do, is to set the home directory for the user. This can be done with `sudo usermod --home /path/to/home/ username`. It will not move any files, although you can do that as well if you provide the --move-home option.

I don't think you want to deny the right to change to the parent directory. That would be problematic and would serve no useful purpose. You need a way to access your home directory, so the parent must be accessible. What you probably *do* want, is to deny the right to see the *content* of the parent directory. That's something else. The *execute bit* (x) is used to allow people to change into a directory, whereas the read bit (r) is used to allow listing of files and directories contained in that directory.

You might simply do a `sudo chmod o-r /var/www`. Now, anyone (o="others") will still be allowed to cd into /var/www, but if they try to do an `ls -la`, they will get a permission denied error.

So the permissions for /var/www should look like rwxrwx--x.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait to get back to you, appreciate the help. Was exactly what I was looking for and I have taken on board what you mentioned about denying change to parent directory. Thanks!